# Find examples of a probability density function for which $f$ or $f'$ is unbounded and $f'''$ is bounded

Tags: real-analysis, probability, analysis, statistics

## Setup

Let $f$ be a probability density function, where $f$ or $f'$ is unbounded, and $f'''$ is a bounded function.

## What I think

$f(x) = x^3$ is satisfying the $f'''$ condition, but $f$ is not a probability density function.

If $f$ is Gaussian, then $f'''$ is bounded, but $f$ is bounded.

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Why is $f'''$ unbounded when $f(x)=x^{3}$?

Comment: I made a mistake in writing the setup. Corrected.

Comment: Exponential. normal etc etc.

Comment: Okey, but I want to find  function $f$ which is unbounded.

Comment: Be clear about what you want to ask and make sure that the question matches the title.

Comment: sorry, corrected the title and body.

Comment: What does it mean, "or"? Does a function $f$ qualify if (a) it is a PDF; (b) $f'''$ is bounded; and (c) $f$ is unbounded but $f'$ is bounded? Or do both $f$ and $f'$ have to be unbounded?

Comment: Also: Where did this question come from?

Comment: @BrianTung $f$ is a PDF, $f'''$ is bounded. And either $f$ or $f'$ (or both) must be unbounded.

Comment: @BrianTung I am currently working on Kernel Density Estimator in university, and I needed an example like this.

Comment: Are you certain such an example exists?

Comment: I don’t know if there are any.

Comment: I was going to say this seems not possible, but I suppose someone has beaten me to the punch.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

**tl;dr Obviously impossible.**

Provided that you read *"$f'''$ is bounded"* as *"$f'''$ **exists everywhere and** is bounded"* (which you most likely do, otherwise a counterexample would be relatively trivial), this is not possible, and here is why.

1. Say, at some point we have $f(x_0)=C>0$. Now, $f(x)$ can't be $\geqslant C$ everywhere between $-\infty$ and $x_0$, otherwise the integral would diverge; hence it must be less than $C$ at some point (say, $x_1$). Ditto for the right half-line (that would be $x_2$).
2. On the segment between $x_1$ and $x_2$, the function (being triple-differentiable, hence differentiable, hence continuous) inevitably reaches a maximal value, which is greater or equal to $C$ and hence is not located at either of the ends. This must be a local maximum where the derivative equals $0$.
3. Together with the non-boundedness of $f$, this means that we have local maxima greater than any number (and greater than that, too).
4. Here goes the gist of my reasoning: for a maximum high enough, descending from it too fast will run us into the ground, while descending too slowly will make the area under the peak too great, hence neither is possible.

Now come the details. Say we have a local maximum $f(0)=C$ (I shifted the origin there, because why the heck not). With our function being triple-differentiable, hence doubly differentiable, hence differentiable, this means zero first derivative and a non-positive second derivative. Say, $f''(0)=-a$. Also, we know that $|f'''(x)|\leqslant M$ everywhere, which means that for $x>0$:
$$\begin{aligned}
f''(x)&=-a+\int\limits_0^xf'''(t)\,dt \leqslant -a+Mx\\
f'(x)&=\int\limits_0^xf''(t)\,dt      \leqslant -ax+{1\over2}Mx^2\\
f(x)&=C+\int\limits_0^xf'(t)\,dt      \leqslant C-{1\over2}ax^2+{1\over6}Mx^3\\
f({2a/M})&\leqslant C-{2\over3}a^3/M^2
\end{aligned}
$$

For this to be non-negative, we must have ${2\over3}a^3/M^2\leqslant C$, or $a\leqslant \sqrt[3]{{3\over2}C\,M^2}$.

Now is the time for the *opposite* estimate.
$$\begin{aligned}
f''(x)&=-a+\int\limits_0^xf'''(t)\,dt \geqslant -a-Mx\\
f'(x)&=\int\limits_0^xf''(t)\,dt      \geqslant -ax-{1\over2}Mx^2\\
f(x)&=C+\int\limits_0^xf'(t)\,dt      \geqslant C-{1\over2}ax^2-{1\over6}Mx^3\\
\int\limits_0^{\sqrt[3]{C/M}}f(x)\,dx         & \geqslant \left.\left(Cx-{1\over6}ax^3-{1\over24}Mx^4\right)\right|_0^{\sqrt[3]{C/M}} =
\end{aligned}\\
 = {23\over24}\frac{C^{4/3}}{M^{1/3}}-{1\over6}a \frac CM
 \geqslant \underbrace{\left({23\over24}-{1\over6}\sqrt[3]{3\over2} \right)}_{>0} \frac{C^{4/3}}{M^{1/3}}
$$
By making $C$ great enough (which we know we can), this integral can be made greater than anything, and in particular, greater than $1$, which means that $f(x)$ can't be a probability density function.

The case of bounded $f(x)$ and unbounded $f'(x)$ is treated in pretty much the same way.

Q.e.d.